# Best color palette for a sober, elegant look and feel

Tags: color, color-scheme

I am building a web app whose target audience will be musicians in general but more specifically classical musicians. So in my limited, more accurately nonexistent, knowledge of user experience and use of colors (I am a software developer); to give it an elegant, sort of intellectual look and feel I thought it would be a good idea to go with the "controversial" dark theme.

Now my biggest problem is that I have no idea which colors to use for text, buttons, links and such, that will make sense and work harmoniously together with the dark background.

In a nutshell the application is just a collection of cards that represent the music pieces the user knows and the colors I am using so far are the following:

Body Background: #2E2E2E
Body text: #FFF8DC

hr: #949494

Navigation bar background: #343a40
Navigation bar text/links: white with 0.5 opacity

Music piece card background: #1E1E1E
Music piece card text: #FFF8DC

Primary buttons: #5EB4CC
Secondary buttons: #545b62

Links: haven't been able to make up my mind yet.

Like I said options for the text, buttons and links colors are the main concern, that being said, if there are better options for the whole color palette to give the application that feeling of elegance and intellectual look I definitely appreciate your insight and expertise.

Thank you.

Comment: You are asking a question about colors, something totally visual and in the question you just put hexadecimal numbers... It existe the superhero who visualizes colors through hexadecimal codes? I think you should take the effort to at least make a mockup.

Comment: You might have better luck at getting good answers at Graphic Design SE (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Color is very subjective! So I will give you my opinion first, and then some rules-of-thumb and tools to help you going forward.

I like that you have selected a dark gray (not full black) background with a cream (not stark white) foreground. I would suggest using blue for links, either the same as your primary buttons or a little lighter. #9dd2e1 will contrast your text color nicely and still stand out from the dark gray backgrounds, with added bonus that it is a shade of the blue you selected for primary buttons, giving an affordance of clickability to both of them.

First, the super handy tool I used to come up with my suggested shade of blue: https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp I plugged in your blue button color and selected one that was about 20% lighter.

Here are a few things to keep in mind as you select colors:

1. Be sure there is contrast so that the text, links, etc. are easy to read and find. All of your selections have passed this tool: https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/
2. Desaturated colors are best on a dark background. Google's Material Design shows it well: https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html#ui-application
3. Once you select a color scheme, stick to it. Too many colors tend to look less professional. This site has some helpful tips:  https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_schemes.asp